# Sound Stops working after I close my laptop lid

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

My laptop's (hp envy touchsmart 15, running ubuntu 13.10) audio stops working after the laptop sleeps or if I close my laptop lid (the current setting are the on closing the lid the laptop does not go to sleep). Another thing I have noticed the light on the mute button does not also work after the sound stops (the keyboard backlit lights still work). My laptop has a subwoofer as well - this could be the problem....

I have tried to follow the steps to restart the sound (i.e. kill pulseaudio and restart; uninstall pulseaudio and reinstall...)

when I run `lsof | grep pcm` (I don't know what this means but saw it on a tutorial to fix audio); I see 10 things - let me know if I should copy and paste it here.

The sounds work if I restart the laptop. Is there any way to restart the audio with restarting the laptop....
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a driver problem most likely. Try updating them. After you close and reopen your lid, use terminal to kill and start all audio programs. If that works then you may want to make shortcuts for those commands.